# comment trouble

Tags: support, mathjax, comment

I made a mistake in typing some MathJAX in a [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/455470/inverse-fourier-transform-of-1-pm-hatfw-1/455552?noredirect=1#comment980138_455552), and the mistake is such that I cannot edit or erase the comment(s).  (Yes, I also duplicated the comment.  Ugh.)  How do I fix this?

Comment: I once had a similar problem with my comment running well into the margin covering the "Related" area (and thus making the edit-icon unclickable). Flagging the comment/answer together with a suitable accompanying note caused a friendly moderator to drop by and fix things.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: thanks, I will.

Comment: It happened to me as well. I think we can call that a "bug".

Comment: Maybe you can post what you did, since the problem seems to be fixed now. At least I don't see any trouble at the linked post...

Comment: Was it the same problem as describe [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2652/comments-layout-break-if-math-expression-is-too-long)?

Comment: Problem with formula inn comments which is too long is also described in several other posts tagged [comment+tex](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comment+tex).

Comment: @MartinSleziak: yes.  And it looks like someone came to my rescue.  Thanks all!

Comment: Yeah, I saw that it was deleted.  I wish that I didn't have to see what was left over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, a fix for this issue is to flag the comment with a note to the moderators explaining the situation.

Comment: Well, I tried that, but I couldn't find a flag -- it is that messed up.  I flagged the original question, which isn't good, but couldn't think of anything else.